# Finding an alternate route using Cypher and Memgraph

Tags: memgraphdb

I have a situation where I have several data centers spread across large distances. I have a main site and a backup site.

There are several routes between main and backup site. Based on conditions (connectivity issues) I need to decide which route to activate for data transfer.

I have all of the data on datacenters, routes and server characteristics stored as nodes and relationships in Memgraph.

How would a Cypher query look for a decision making scenario to chose to optimal route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue can be solved using [WSHORTEST algorithm](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/reference-guide/built-in-graph-algorithms#weighted-shortest-path). The code for this scenario could be something like this:

```
MATCH p=(n:Node3 {prop:"c"})-[r *wShortest (e,v | 1) sum]->(t:Target), (n2:Node2 {prop:"b"})
WHERE not n2 in nodes(p)
RETURN p
ORDER BY sum DESC;
```